# No implicit conversion of HTTParty::Response into String

Tags: ruby, json

When I am trying to parse some kind of response into JSON I am getting the following error. I have raised JSON::ParserError in my code if incase parsing fails. But this kind of exception does not come under this parser error. I don't know why this kind of error is thrown? and How to rescue this error?

code:

```
 begin
   parsed_response = JSON.parse(response)
 rescue JSON::ParserError => e
   nil
 end
```

Error:

```
A TypeError occurred in background at 2014-11-16 03:01:08 UTC :

  no implicit conversion of HTTParty::Response into String
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The error you're getting is a `TypeError`. It's raised when you pass the wrong kind of argument to certain methods. You can rescue it like this:

```
# not ideal - see below
begin
  parsed_response = JSON.parse(response)
rescue JSON::ParserError, TypeError => e
  puts e
end
```

I wouldn't recommend this, though. The reason you're getting a `TypeError` is that `JSON.parse` requires a `String` object, and you've passed it a `HTTParty::Response` object. Try giving it a `String` object instead. e.g.:

```
# better
parsed_response = JSON.parse(response&.body || "{}")
```

This way, a `nil` value in either `response` or `response.body` returns a usable object. In this example, the object is an empty `Hash`, though you can replace the JSON string with whatever value you want to represent a "nothing there" value (e.g. `"[]"` or `"null"`).

Comment: response.body does not work out for all responses. so TypeError is the only solution to rescue this

Comment: I agree it is not always going to work. For instance when the response code is :no_content (204) then the response body is nil, which  is not an error.

Comment: It's easy to work around the `nil` response body. I've updated the answer to reflect one technique.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the inbuilt `to_s` method to convert to string.

```
response = HTTParty.get(<any_url>)
response_string = response.to_s
```